# How do I figure out the which CPU the Sony DPF C-1000 has?

Tags: hardware

Recently I received a Digital Photo Frame (Sony C-1000) and since I'll never use it as it is, I thought of playing with it and reprogram it. Anything like managing to print out to screen "Hello world" would be a win.

I'm trying to understand which CPU is used; next step would be how to access it. Any hint would be great, because I'm not experienced with hardware.
I opened the device thinking I'd see the CPU, with its model written on top. I think I identified the processor, but the code written on its top did not help me.

Thanks for any pointers.

On top of what it looks like the CPU reads:
`G+ SPMF2892A M0023520 1124`

A piece that I could identify is the RAM:
`EtronTech EM639165TS-6G
N48AG05AGB640.12ZQ`

Comment: What *is* written on top of it?

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky I added info in the main post.
Is it legal/allowed to post a picture of the circuit? If yes, I guess this might help.

Comment: @CuriousMind it is a SunPlus Multi Media SPMF-2800 ... shows up in a few forums and you can buy them on a few trade sites. Nothing on a datasheet for you but I highly suspect it is Arm.

Answer (score 4):

Ok.. so here is what I [gather](http://hackmii.com/2010/04/sunplus-the-biggest-chip-company-youve-never-heard-of/). Which leads me to this [GeneralPlus link](http://www.generalplus.com/product.php?prot_no=8&func=sh).

Looks like it has these interfaces:

JPEG codec, 6-in-1 card I/F and digital panel I/F

On that generalplus page if you click on the title of the chip you get a blank frame. The source for that frame has a bit of content in it. After looking through the html code of thier site I found spec listings that failed get filled out as well as php generated datasheet download links that also are messed up.

I imagine if you email them they might possibly send you the link worth a shot at least.

[broken html 1](http://www.generalplus.com/product_detail.php?&psn=U1BNRjI4OTJB&?pdv_no=47&func=dl#doc)

[broken spec table](http://www.generalplus.com/product_detail.php?&psn=U1BNRjI4OTJB)

Comment: Thank you very much! It's going to be a long way (for me at least), but this is a good starting point.

Comment: Do you think theoretically it can be reprogrammed? Or the only way is to access it via JPEG inputs?

Comment: oh its definitly an mcu I poked around the HTML of thier site a bit... its quite broken

Comment: It looks like there is supposed to be downloads for the ROM and Datasheet... but well its borked.

Comment: I think this is their email gpcode@generalplus.com

Comment: cb88 this is very helpful, I'll give it a shot!

Answer (score 3):

From looking at firmware updates for some other Sony frames, the processor seem to be mostly 8051 derivatives. A couple of them expect files with names like `ISP.vup` and `VISP.vup`. You could try putting such files on a card and seeing if you can trigger the [firmware update mode](http://www.sony.co.uk/support/en/product/DPF-D80/downloads/DPF_D80_fw) (but don't update it!). If this works, you can investigate the firmware update and try to write some simple code that would run instead.